# c# data objects accidently updating

Tags: c#, unity-container, repository-pattern

We are having a problem where the data is fetched from the repository, and manipulated in the business layer, and these updates are being unintentionally saved back to the database.

We had been working under the assumption that the database context was disconnected and that data was only updated when we called a specific save method.

Our repository class looks like the following:

```
  public class OdsRepository : IOdsRepository, IDisposable
{
    public OdsContext DbContext { get; set; }

    public List<QueueErrorItem> GetQueueErrorItems<T>()
    {
        Type t = typeof(T);
        var ret = DbContext.QueueErrorItems.Where(p => p.DataType == t.Name).ToList();
        return ret;
    }

    public OdsRepository()
    {
        DbContext = new OdsContext();
    }

    public ApiKey CreateApiKey(ApiKey apiKey)
    {
        var ret = DbContext.ApiKeys.Add(apiKey);
        return ret;
    }
```

I don't think we should be instantiating the context in the default constructor, we are using Unity IOC, so I think this may be related to the problem.

Essentially what happens is that we will call one of the reopsitory methods from the business object to fetch some data, and then if that data is further manipulated to be used in another method, that change can then be unintentionially updated back into the database.

Can anyone help with diagnosing either repository code changes or unity changes that would make the data objects truly disconnected?

Comment: Someone is reusing the same DbContext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behavior of Entity Framework. Any changes you make to entities returned from the context will be saved once you do a .SaveChanges().    My team had a similar scenario where we needed to construct temporary data within our object model for display purposes. We ended up utilizing AsNoTracking() for our view only data. This method removes entity frameworks hooks and prevents inadvertent database updates.

Quick Example:

```
    public class Provider<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        protected IObjectSet<TEntity> _dbSet;
        protected ObjectContext _context;

        public Provider(ObjectContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            _dbSet = context.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> whereClause= null)
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> dbSet = _dbSet;

            if (whereClause!= null) 
                dbSet = dbSet.AsExpandable().Where(whereClause);

            return dbSet;
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> FindReadOnly(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> whereClause= null)
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> dbSet = _dbSet.AsNoTracking();

            if (whereClause!= null) 
                dbSet = dbSet.AsExpandable().Where(whereClause);

            return dbSet;
        }
    }
```

Note the simple Find method will allow you to gather entities while still keeping the Entity Framework Change Tracker enabled.  While the ReadOnly counterpart simply decouples the ChangeTracker from the returned entities.

Comment: Thanks for this jigear. Do you know whether I can close the context by managing how Unity instantiates the repository. It strikes me that I really want a new DbContext per call, or possibly I always want change tracking to be turned off

Comment: I'm not as familiar with WPF but if you are using MVC the lifetime will be limited to the Action scope using a HierarchicalLifetimeManager.